# How to create the pseudo static rules of the page I created

Tags: url-rewriting

I am a Chinese WordPress developer, I am not familiar with English, all the content is Machine Translation.

> 我是一个中国的WordPress的开发者，我不熟悉英语，所有的内容都是机器翻译。

I would like to create a separate comment page for my site.

> 我希望能为我的网站创建一个单独的评论显示页面

This is my idea:

> 我的想法如下

I created a **postcomment-page.php** page on my WordPress Theme

it's URL is **xxx.com/postcomment-page**

I have a **$_GET['postid']** and a **$_GET['paged']** on this page.

A total of two get requests,

Normal URL:**xxxx.com/?pagename=postcomment-page&postid={postid}&paged={paged}**

I would like to URL: **xxxx.com/postcomment-page/{postid}-paged-{paged}.html**

So I can get to the two GET request.

But I tried various ways to use it.

Ask you to help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In focus on comment of the site, the need for such a design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)! First things first let's get that in place:

```
function wpse_226796_rewrite_rule( $rules ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php
    $regex = 'postcomment-page/([1-9][0-9]*)-paged-([1-9][0-9]*)\.html';

    $query = sprintf(
        '%s?pagename=postcomment-page&postid=%s&paged=%s',
        $wp_rewrite->index,
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 )
    );

    // Push our rule to the top of $rules
    return array( $regex => $query ) + $rules;
}

add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_226796_rewrite_rule' );
```

Next we need to register our query vars so that WordPress correctly parses the "pretty" permalink into our query:

```
function wpse_226796_query_vars( $vars ) {
    // "paged" is already a core public query var
    $vars[] = 'postid';

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_226796_query_vars' );
```

Now we need to "flush" these rules to the database cache - **go to Settings > Permalinks and click Save**.

Now a URL like `postcomment-page/237-paged-2.html` will give:

```
<?php echo get_query_var( 'postid' ); // 237 ?>
<?php echo get_query_var( 'paged' ); // 2 ?>
```

Comment: By the way you provide, the content of my output is

$matches[1] and 0

$matches[1] is a string content

Comment: hello? please help me.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is

Comment: Is my reference to the way you operate, did not achieve the desired effect, although the setting of the URL has been able to access, but the get_query_var function to get the content is "$matches[1]" and "0""

Comment: Oh okay can you try my updated answer and then re-save your permalinks.